# Why are my Flink windows using so much state?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The checkpoints for my Flink job are getting larger and larger. After drilling down into individual tasks, the keyed window function seems to be responsible for most of the size. How can I reduce this?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of state tied up in windows, there are several possibilities:

- Using incremental aggregation (by using `reduce` or `aggregate`) can dramatically reduce your storage requirements. Otherwise each event is being copied into the list of events assigned to each window.
- If you are aggregating over multiple timeframes, e.g., every minute and every 10 minutes, you can cascade these windows, so that the 10 minute windows are only consuming the output of the minute-long windows, rather than every event.
- If you are using sliding windows, each event is being assigned to each of the overlapping windows. For example, if your windows are 2 minutes long and sliding by 1 second, each event is being copied into 120 windows. Incremental and/or pre-aggregation will help here (a lot!), or you may want to use a `KeyedProcessFunction` instead of a window in order to optimize your state footprint.
- If you have keyed count windows, you could have keys for which the requisite batch size is never (or only very slowly) reached, leading to more and more partial batches sitting around in state. You could implement a custom `Trigger` that incorporates a timeout in addition to the count-based triggering so that these partial batches are eventually processed.
- If you are using `globalState` in a `ProcessWindowFunction`, the globalState for stale keys will accumulate. You can use state TTL on the state descriptor for the globalState. Note: this is the only place where window state isn't automatically freed when windows are cleared.
- Or it may simply be that your key space is growing over time, and there's really nothing that can be done except to scale up the cluster.