# How to work on Flink Apache with big keyed?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

On my stream application, it will receive 70k records of data per second. Each record has a key (FQDN).

Example record coming data:

```
{
  "unixTime" : 1680064946,
  "FQDN" : "sub1.example1.com",
  "volume": 20

}
----
{
  "unixTime" : 1680064946,
  "FQDN" : "sub2.example2.com",
  "volume": 5
}
```

My code:

```
case class Event(unixTime: Long, FQDN: String, volume: Long)

object App {
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  private val gson = new Gson()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val builder = PulsarSourceBuilder
      .builder(new SimpleStringSchema())
      .topic("my-topic")
      .subscriptionName("my-sub")
      .subscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Latest)

    val clientConfig = new ClientConfigurationData()
    clientConfig.setServiceUrl("pulsar://localhost:6650")
    val src = builder.pulsarAllClientConf(clientConfig).build()

    val windowCounts = env.addSource(src).map(m => parser(m))
      .keyBy(_.FQDN)
      .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(24), Time.minutes(1)))
      .sum("volume")
    windowCounts.addSink(mySink)
    env.execute("myJobName")
  }

  private final def parser(message: String): Event = {
    try {
      gson.fromJson(message, classOf[Event])
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(e.getMessage)
        null
    }
  }
}
```

My VM Infomation:

```
MEMORY: 5GB
vCPU: 4
```

---

My stream application use window-size: 24hour and Window-slide: 1min.
With 70k records per second, My stream is always OOM.
How to resolve this problem?

Thanks,
ChienNguyen

Answer (score 0):

This is where SO can be so helpful - a search turned up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472206/why-are-my-flink-windows-using-so-much-state). But to do the math, 24 hours * 60 minutes/hour * cardinality of your FQDN key == number of state records you need to keep around.